# Rails ActiveRecord has_many issue

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User that has many tasks.  This is a predefined set of tasks.  Each task has a list of requirements that need to be completed for the task to be finished.  I have set up 2 `has_many through` relationships.  Here is my code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :user_tasks
end

class UserTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tasks
  has_many :users, through: :user_tasks
  has_many :task_requirements
  has_many :requirements, through: :task_requirements
end

class TaskRequirement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :requirement
end

class Requirement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_requirements
  has_many :requirements, through: :tasks
end
```

This part seems fairly simple, but now I want to capture the date that each requirement is completed and a boolean of whether it is completed or not for each `User`.  I originally tried to put it in the `TaskRequirement` table, but of course then it was updated for all users, which is not the behavior that I want.  So I have 2 questions. 
1.  Where do I put these fields?
2.  what is the best way to access them?

I assume they will go in a join table, but there is no easy way to access the information in the join tables.

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Under Requirement, "has_many :requirements, through: :tasks" should presumably be "has_many :taskss, through: :task_requirements". And don't forget your inverse associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each user completes the task requirements independently of whether other users have completed the task, then you need a UserRequirement table to store the associated data items -- the boolean and the completion date.

However, if each requirement has to be completed multiple times by each user, once for every task with which it is associated, then you'd need a join between User and TaskRequirement, or UserTask and Requirement, or User and Task and Requirement.